# UnitTest for adding items to list in foreach

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I've got a this (working) code I need to refactor so I can unit test (with moq) if packages are added to the IList and if for each package LoadContexts and LoadModules is run.

```
private Package[] _getPackages()
    {
        string[] files = _directory.GetFiles(_moduleDirectory, "*.dll", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            string relativePath = file.Substring(_baseDirectory.Count());
            Package package = new Package(relativePath);
            package.LoadContexts();
            package.LoadModules();
            if (package.Contexts.Count() > 0 && package.Modules.Count() > 0)
            {
                _packages.Add(package);
            }
        }

        return _packages.ToArray();
    }
```

I was thinking of making a separate PackageList class with a IPackageList interface and let this class handle adding and loading the packages. This way I can verify if those methods are used and make a separate test for the PackageList class.

Is this a good approach or is there a better pattern to test this?

Answer (score 1):

I like your proposed architecture: it separates the concerns of loading and managing lists of packages from the packages themselves as well as from the consumer of the packages.  You will be able to easily test loading new packages independently.

One tweak I would make: don't call it just PackageList, since that name doesn't justify wrapping the data structure in a new class.  Name it something that evokes the logical purpose.  Perhaps PackageManager or PackageLoader, since it seems to be responsible for those types of duties.